# Load contents of .rtf file into RichTextBox Control

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build an Excel application with UserForms. In a UserForm, I've successfully added RichTextBoxes. I have also successfully coded a button to save all RichTextBox contents in an .rtf file.

This is where I'm stuck:

There does not seem to be a way to load the contents of an rtf file into a RichTextBox.

I've flipped through 5 pages of various google searches, but none gave any clues towards Excel VBA... all were on C#...

Speaking of C#, when I try something similar such as .rtfOne.LoadFile(filePath) I get an error:

> Run-Time error '75':
>   The specified Path/file name cannot be accessed or is invalid.

Code I tried:

```
Dim filePath As String
filePath = "C:\Users\Donkey\Desktop\Test One\" & Cells(1,1)
UserForm.richtextbox1.LoadFile(filePath & "richtextfile.rtf")
```

I have included a MsgBox in my code to see how the compiler reads this line, it is read correctly as:

```
C:\Users\Donkey\Desktop\Test One\2019AA-10000V1richtextfile.rtf
```

Comment: .LoadFile() is the way to do it, double check the path is what you think it is (full paths are best)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your code and a [mcve]. We cannot help you if we don't see your code (see [ask]).

Comment: You actually have a file named `2019AA-10000V1richtextfile.rtf` in the folder `C:\Users\Donkey\Desktop\Test One`?